# Beautiful Soup find is returning empty value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the list of restaurants from this website

https://www.352delivery.com/order/restaurants

So far, I code this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.352delivery.com/order/restaurants'

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

restaurant_wrapper = soup.find(class_ = "restaurant-card-info-wrapper")
print(restaurant_wrapper)
```

The result is "None" I do not why, I tried with different names of class. Am I scraping the wrong div?

Answer (score 0):

Issue here in my opinion is, you have to enter a valid adress/street, before all resturants will be loaded and the cards will be displayed.

May check this url to get the restaurants instead:

```
https://www.352delivery.com/restaurants
```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.352delivery.com/restaurants'

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

restaurant_wrapper = soup.find_all(class_ = "restaurant-card-info-wrapper")
print(restaurant_wrapper)
```

###### Output

```
[<div class="restaurant-card-info-wrapper">
<div class="restaurant-card-logo">
<img alt="Munecas Downtown Taco Garden" class="lazy" data-src="https://deliverlogic-common-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/editable/images/three52d/logos/front/55.jpg" height="52" title="Munecas Downtown Taco Garden" width="52"/>
</div>
<div class="restaurant-card-info">
<p class="restaurant-card-title">Munecas Downtown Taco Garden</p>
<p class="restaurant-card-cuisine">Indonesian, Locally Sourced, Mexican, Tex-Mex
                </p>
<p class="restaurant-card-minimum"></p>
<p class=""></p>
</div>
</div>, <div class="restaurant-card-info-wrapper">
<div class="restaurant-card-logo">
<img alt="The Leaning Pig" class="lazy" data-src="https://deliverlogic-common-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/editable/images/three52d/logos/front/99.png" height="52" title="The Leaning Pig" width="52"/>
</div>
<div class="restaurant-card-info">
<p class="restaurant-card-title">The Leaning Pig</p>
<p class="restaurant-card-cuisine">Charcuteries, Deli, International, Subs/Sandwich
                </p>
<p class="restaurant-card-minimum"></p>
<p class=""></p>
</div>
</div>,...]
```